# Android- Unable to show received location values due to java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create a layout that will show the received location updates in the text view, but i keep getting this error, what am i doing wrong?

Help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Here is the error:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                    Process: com.example.defro.app, PID: 7731
>                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual >method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null >object reference
>                         at com.example.defro.app.MainActivity$1.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:29)`

**Row 29 is:**

`txtLoc.setText(String.valueOf(iaLocation.getLongitude() + ", " + iaLocation.getLatitude()));`

**Main_Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

IALocationManager mLocationManager;
IALocationListener mLocationListener = new IALocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(IALocation iaLocation) {
        TextView txtLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        txtLoc.setText(String.valueOf(iaLocation.getLongitude() + ", " + iaLocation.getLatitude()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

};
private final int CODE_PERMISSIONS = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLocationManager = IALocationManager.create(this);


    String[] neededPermissions = {
            Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN



    };
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, neededPermissions, CODE_PERMISSIONS);


}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    //Handle if any of the permissions are denied, in grantResults
}


protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(IALocationRequest.create(), mLocationListener);

}

protected void onPause() {
    mLocationManager.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationListener);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onDestroy() {

   mLocationManager.destroy();
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

**content_main.xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:text="Lat, Long"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.032" />
```

Comment: Code review `String.valueOf()` is unnecessary if there is `","` already...

Answer (score 2):

Write this line inside the onCreate method

```
TextView txtLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Add id to TextView

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong!

Comment: Your answer is wrong..

Comment: Didn't see that the id was missing xD EDITED!

Comment: Nice then +1 for the edit..

Comment: Thank you, this solved the error, but it still does not show the received values, only "lat,long" shows up on the screen

Comment: Well the error got fixed that's great xD 
TextView not getting updated must be because onLocationChanged method might not be called. Try implementing with the help of this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218419/how-do-i-implement-the-locationlistener?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

You are linking up your **TextView** as `TextView txtLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);`

However there is no **ID** defined in your XML layout file.
Define your Textview id in `content_main.xml` like `android:id="@+id/textView"`

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, the textView does not seem to have the

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```

that may be y its failing to find the view. Additionally, you probably want to get the reference to the textView in the `onCreate()` and use it along with a null check just incase.